# How to apply a function with multiple arguments to a specific column in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, apply

I'm trying to apply a function to a specific column in this dataframe

```
       datetime       PM2.5        PM10         SO2         NO2  
0    2013-03-01    7.125000   10.750000   11.708333   22.583333   
1    2013-03-02   30.750000   42.083333   36.625000   66.666667  
2    2013-03-03   76.916667  120.541667   61.291667   81.000000 
3    2013-03-04   22.708333   44.583333   22.854167   46.187500 
4    2013-03-06  223.250000  265.166667  116.236700  142.059383
5    2013-03-07  263.375000  316.083333   97.541667  147.750000
6    2013-03-08  221.458333  297.958333   69.060400  120.092788
```

I'm trying to apply this function(below) to a specific column(PM10) of the above dataframe:

```
range1 = [list(range(0,50)),list(range(51,100)),list(range(101,200)),list(range(201,300)),list(range(301,400)),list(range(401,2000))]

def c1_c2(x,y):
for a in y:
    if x in a:
        min_val = min(a)
        max_val = max(a)+1
        return max_val - min_val
```

## Where "x" can be any column and "y" = Range1

**Available Options**

```
df.PM10.apply(c1_c2,args(df.PM10,range1),axis=1)
df.PM10.apply(c1_c2)
```

I've tried these couple of available options and none of them seems to be working. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is `x` and `y` with respect to the column `PM10`?

Comment: x = PM10 or any other column, and y = range1 .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the expected output is from the function. But to get the function getting called you can try the following

```py
from functools import partial

df.PM10.apply(partial(c1_c2, y=range1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Ok, I think I understand a little better.  This should work, but 'range1' is a list of lists of integers. Your data doesn't have integers and the new column comes up empty.  I created another list based on your initial data that works.  See below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('pm_data.txt', header=0)

range1= [[7.125000,10.750000,11.708333,22.583333],list(range(0,50)),list(range(51,100)),list(range(101,200)),
list(range(201,300)),list(range(301,400)),list(range(401,2000))]

def c1_c2(x,y):
  for a in y:
    if x in a:
        min_val = min(a)
        max_val = max(a)+1
        return max_val - min_val

df['function']=df.PM10.apply(lambda x: c1_c2(x,range1))

print(df.head(10))

datetime       PM2.5        PM10         SO2         NO2  new_column   function
0  2013-03-01    7.125000   10.750000   11.708333   22.583333   25.750000  16.458333
1  2013-03-02   30.750000   42.083333   36.625000   66.666667    2.104167        NaN
2  2013-03-03   76.916667  120.541667   61.291667   81.000000    6.027083        NaN
3  2013-03-04   22.708333   44.583333   22.854167   46.187500    2.229167        NaN
4  2013-03-06  223.250000  265.166667  116.236700  142.059383   13.258333        NaN
5  2013-03-07  263.375000  316.083333   97.541667  147.750000   15.804167        NaN
6  2013-03-08  221.458333  297.958333   69.060400  120.092788   14.897917        NaN
```

Only the first item in 'function' had a match because it came from your initial data because of 'if x in a'.

---

Old Code:

I'm also not sure what you are doing. But you can use a lambda to modify columns or create new ones.

Like this,

```
import pandas as pd
```

I created a data file to import from the data you posted above:

```
datetime,PM2.5,PM10,SO2,NO2
2013-03-01,7.125000,10.750000,11.708333,22.583333   
2013-03-02,30.750000,42.083333,36.625000,66.666667  
2013-03-03,76.916667,120.541667,61.291667,81.000000 
2013-03-04,22.708333,44.583333,22.854167,46.187500 
2013-03-06,223.250000,265.166667,116.236700,142.059383
2013-03-07,263.375000,316.083333,97.541667,147.750000
2013-03-08,221.458333,297.958333,69.060400,120.092788
```

Here is how I import it,

```
df = pd.read_csv('pm_data.txt', header=0)
```

and create a new column and apply a function to the data in 'PM10'

```
df['new_column'] = df['PM10'].apply(lambda x: x+15 if x < 30 else x/20)
```

which yields,

```
    datetime       PM2.5        PM10         SO2         NO2  new_column
0  2013-03-01    7.125000   10.750000   11.708333   22.583333   25.750000
1  2013-03-02   30.750000   42.083333   36.625000   66.666667    2.104167
2  2013-03-03   76.916667  120.541667   61.291667   81.000000    6.027083
3  2013-03-04   22.708333   44.583333   22.854167   46.187500    2.229167
4  2013-03-06  223.250000  265.166667  116.236700  142.059383   13.258333
5  2013-03-07  263.375000  316.083333   97.541667  147.750000   15.804167
6  2013-03-08  221.458333  297.958333   69.060400  120.092788   14.897917
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

#### "I've tried these couple of available options and none of them seems to be working..."

---

What do you mean by this? What's your output, are you getting errors or what?

I see a couple of problems:

- `range1` lists contain `int` while your column values are `float`, so `c1_c2()` will return `None`.
- if the data types were the same within `range1` and `columns`, `c1_c2()` will return `None` when value is not in `range1`.

---

Below is how I would do it, assuming the data-types match:

```
def c1_c2(x):
    range1 = [list of lists]
    for a in range1:
        if x in a:
            min_val = min(a)
            max_val = max(a)+1
            return max_val - min_val
        return x # returns the original value if not in range1

df.PM10.apply(c1_c2)
```